# How can I create a custom report in Experience Analytics?

Tags: xdb, mongodb, experience-analytics

I'm pretty new at Sitecore, so I don't know if this is possible. I am able to log some custom page events (click on an anchor on the client side) in xDB. I can then query this with Robomongo. But besides that I need to create a report that displays this information.

How can I create a new report in Experience Analytics that accesses the information in MongoDB? I have been trying to pass the MongoDB values to a fact table in the Reporting database, but no luck so far.

Comment: Could you please share the logic how are you logging the custom events and query for mongodb also

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, it is a kind of difficult sometimes to query the MongoDB directly, I had a similar scenario and following what I did:

I created aggregation processor that will be called when you rebuild the analytics database or when aggregation occurs:

```cs
public class PageEventProcessor : AggregationProcessor
{
    protected override void OnProcess(AggregationPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        var fact = args.GetFact<PageEvent>();
        foreach (var page in args.Context.Visit.Pages)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var pEvent in page.PageEvents)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var eventkey = new PageEventKey
                        {
                            EventId = pEvent.PageEventDefinitionId,
                            Date = args.DateTimeStrategy.Translate(pEvent.DateTime),
                            ItemId = pEvent.ItemId,
                            PageId = page.Item.Id
                        };
                        var eventValue = new PageEventValue
                        {
                            Count = 1
                        };
                        fact.Emit(eventkey, eventValue);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            } 
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classes needed:

```cs
public class PageEventValue : DictionaryValue
{

    public int Count { get; set; }

    internal static PageEventValue Reduce(PageEventValue left, PageEventValue right)
    {
        var profileValue = new PageEventValue
        {
            Count = left.Count + right.Count
        };

        return profileValue;
    }
}

public class PageEvent : Fact<PageEventKey, PageEventValue>
{
    public PageEvent() : base(PageEventValue.Reduce)
    {
    }
}

public class PageEventKey : DictionaryKey
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public Guid PageId { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Also you need to include the following configuration:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="analytics.aggregation">
        <pipelines>
          <interactions>
            <processor type="DllName.PageEventProcessor, DllName" />
          </interactions>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I tried it and it seems to be working great but the fact table doesn't get updated

Comment: add exception handling to the code and check the log files to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 3):

There's a Sitecore guide on how to create custom reports here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/creating-a-custom-experience-analytics-report.html

Steps below:

- Create a report page item based on template `ExperienceAnalyticsReportPage` under: `core/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard`.
- Add a chart rendering to the report page item. You can use an existing one (e.g. `ExperienceAnalyticsAreaChart`)
- Add a parameters item to the `PageSettings` item and set metric and segments of the chart
- Set datasource of chart rendering (step 2) to the recently created parameters items